# SQL Server NULLvalues and Concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Most of my tables have four fields that include:

```
Created datetime not null default = GetDate()
CreatedBy varchar(50) not null default = suser_sname()
Updated datetime null
UpdatedBy Varchar(50) null
```

For data that I display in a grid, I want to combine these fields to show the "Last Edit" in the form of "datetime" by "user".

Knowing that my Created and CreatedBy fields will never be null, Coalesce seems to be the answer but I'm getting errors with the following:

```
,Convert(varchar(20),Coalesce(i.Updated,i.Created) ,120) + ' by ' + Coalesce(i.UpdatedBy,i.Created) as [LastEdit]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all likelihood, the problem is the second `coalesce()`.  I am guessing you mean:

```
(Convert(varchar(20), Coalesce(i.Updated, i.Created), 120) + ' by ' +
 Coalesce(i.UpdatedBy, i.CreatedBy)
--------------------------------^
) as [LastEdit]
```

You were trying to combine a date with a string, which can cause a problem.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - dumb mistake on my part.  Created needs to be CreatedBy in the second coalesce.

Answer (score 1):

Be wary of SQL Server's Concatenate Null Yields Null setting. You may want to either set it to off during your query execution. Or if you have SQL 2012 or higher, use the Concat() function.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx - concat
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx  - set concat_null_yields_null